# Deleting all entries in a Dictionary c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary` which is storing members of a `Skilodge` and I want a method to delete all members. At the moment, it only seems to be removing one. Here is the method I tried:

```
public void DeleteAll()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Skiers.Count; i = i + 1)
    {
        string iString = i.ToString();
        Skiers.Remove(iString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `Skiers.Clear()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978821/how-to-reset-a-dictionary

Comment: Other's have given you answers, but if your keys to your dictionary are just consecutive integers (which your code suggests) then you don't need a dictionary at all. You need a list.

Answer (score 6):

use `Clear` method check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5txwy7s(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Skiers.Clear()
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! Can't accept for 10 minutes but i will do

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Skiers.Clear();` for removing all existing values of the given Dictionary, And you can use `Skiers= new Dictionary<T,T>()`  to get a fresh Dictionary(new instance);

[Dictionary.Clear Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5txwy7s.aspx) will Removes all keys and values from the Dictionary.

You can try Conditional Remove also, Let the Dictionary may defined and initialized as like the following:

```
Dictionary<string, String> dictSample = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictSample.Add("a", "value 1");
dictSample.Add("b", "value 1");
dictSample.Add("c", "value 12");
dictSample.Add("d", "value 10");
dictSample.Add("e", "value 1");
```

And you had a requirement of removing some specific items those are having `value 1` in its value part, then you can use the following code for removing them:

```
var removable = dictSample.Where(x => x.Value == "value 1").Select(x => x.Key).ToList();;
foreach (var dictItem in removable)
{
    dictSample.Remove(dictItem);
}
```

Comment: the conditional remove might throw exception, because you are removing a item of a collection you are iterating. try to use ToArray or ToList before remove.